# Marketing Cloud SDK - geolocation fence error

Tags: marketing-cloud, geolocation, mobilepush-android

I try to receive a push notification when I'm in a specific place but each time the Marketing Cloud SDK send my position to his API service it sent the request with a wrong syntax.

Currently the syntax is:

https://consumer.exacttargetapis.com/device/v1/location/.../fence/?latitude=45,6122649&longitude=8,9479725&deviceid=...

And the service response is:
Error: `400`

```
{
    "message": "Validation Error",
    "errorcode": 10006,
    "documentation": "",
    "validationErrors": [{
        "message": "Latitude is invalid.",
        "errorcode": 10000,
        "documentation": ""
    }, {
        "message": "Longitude is invalid.",
        "errorcode": 10000,
        "documentation": ""
    }]
}
```

The problem seems the comma inside the lat e long vale because if i proxy the request and replace the comma with a dot all works fine.

https://consumer.exacttargetapis.com/device/v1/location/.../fence/?latitude=45.5135901&longitude=9.2235453&deviceid=...

With this request the push service responses with the push notification.

Is it a bug of the SDK or I need some other configuration to change the decimal delimiter?

thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was identified a few days ago.  There is a fix that will be published in the upcoming SDK release.  I'll update this post once it is released.

Comment: This issue is inside the "know issue" of Salesforce? Have you the link?

Answer (score 1):

@frogmouth this has been addressed in our latest SDK version (released yesterday, October 22).

See https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have an external link, however, as Seth mentioned the bug was identified and will be released to production shortly.  I would check back on the Android repo at the close of business on (22-Oct-2018) to see if there is an updated SDK.